# Present popovers without animation in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

Is there any way to present a `.popover()` in macOS without animation in SwiftUI?

Apps like Pages and Keynote present popovers without any animation. I tried this but no luck:

```
Button() { 
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0)) {
        popoverPresented.toggle()
    }
}
```

Xcode 12.2 | SwiftUI 2.0 | Swift 5.2 | macOS 11.0.1